# Python - Convert list to lower case, parse for input value, return input and original (unconverted) list entry

Tags: python, list, case-sensitive

Fairly new to this so apologies if this isn't the most technically demanding question.

I have a large list of file names to search through (around 3k), fairly simple to produce a solution to take an input string, check over the list and tell me if a file is there.
However, the next stage requires me to open the file on another system which is case sensitive.

Essentially I want to input my file name (in any case), check the list for the file name, confirm if the file is present but return the original file name in the correct case.

```
    For example
    search for newfile.txt
    check the list and return the actual case of NeWfILE.txt, perhaps
    newfile.txt found - actual file - NeWfILE.txt or similar
```

I was wondering if anyone could solve this for me.
I've included what I've been playing around with, not the final idea just my working out.

```
    import JSON
    import glob, os
            
    file_name = input("Enter file name you are looking for:  ")
            
    path= (r"C:\Users\Ozzie\new_folder\file_list")
    os.chdir(path)
    list = glob.glob("*.txt")
            
    list_check = {item.lower() for item in list}
    if file_name.lower() in list_check:
        print(file_name +" Found")
    else:
        print(file_name + "Not Found")
```

Comment: Your solution looks pretty reasonable. Using `.lower` on both sides garantees to find the correct files except for the cases where `newFile.txt` and `Newfile.txt` etc. exist.

Comment: I do not know much about Python, but it seems that there is an 'r' out of place in path= (r"C:\Users\Ozzie\new_folder\file_list").

Comment: The 'r' is used for raw string processing in python. It ignores the escape characters on import, i.e. will cause backslashes in the string to be interpreted as actual backslashes rather than special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think changing list_check to a dict should solve your problem. Create a dict that maps the lowercase name of a file to the original name.

It should look something like:

```
list_check = {item.lower(): item for item in list}
if file_name.lower() in list_check:
    print(file_name +" Found as" + list_check[file_name.lower()])
else:
    print(file_name + "Not Found")
```